# A Pivot Table report cannot overlap another Pivot Table report

Tags: excel-2007, pivot-table

Hi I have 3 pivot tables in same sheet and data source is danamically changing when refresh depend on the parameter value which is passing from the front end. It is a report and I have done the layout. But sometimes when the row count is more, Im getting above error message which is "A Pivot Table report cannot overlap another Pivot Table report" .

Do we have any setting to do setup to auto add cells depend on no of rows ? like in tables/data range ?

How can we resolve this issue dynamically ?

Thanks everyone in adavance.

Answer (score 1):

If they are prone to change size there seems little to be gained from having them all in the same worksheet, so hold each in a separate worksheet. Otherwise you should be able to avoid the processing stalling due to overlap by spacing the PTs apart by more than enough blank rows/columns to allow room for as much expansion as would ever be required. If that means the PTs appear too far apart from one another for convenience hide the extra rows/columns until part of one or more PT spills into the hidden area and then unhide as required.